# React - how to make an api request wait for the value of an undefined variable when submitting a form

Tags: reactjs, forms, undefined, submit

I'm trying to make an api request by passing an id parameter in the request url

```
 async function carregarPlanoCurso() {
    const response = await api.get(`cursos/${resPesquisaCurso.id}/plano`);

    return response.data;
  }
```

The problem is that when calling the carregarPlanoCurso in english "loadCoursePlan()" method the variable resPesquisaCurso "searchCoursesearch" is undefined and I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:3001/cursos/undefined/plano 500 (Internal Server Error)

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

The variable resPesquisaCurso depends on the carregarCursos() method which loads all courses which are then filtered according to id:

```
 const [resPesquisaDisciplina, setResPesquisaDisciplina] = useState([]);
  const [resPesquisaCurso, setResPesquisaCurso] = useState([]);
  const [resPesquisaPlano, setResPesquisaPlano] = useState([]);
  const [resPesquisaEdicao, setResPesquisaEdicao] = useState([]);

  const [plan, setPlan] = useState([]);

  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.profile);

  async function carregarDisciplinas() {
    const response = await api.get('disciplinas/');

    return response.data;
  }

  async function carregarCursos() {
    const response = await api.get('cursos/');

    return response.data;
  }

  async function carregarEdicoes() {
    const response = await api.get('disciplinas/all/edicoes');

    return response.data;
  }

  async function carregarPlanoCurso() {
    const response = await api.get(`cursos/${resPesquisaCurso.id}/plano`);

    return response.data;
  }

  function handleSubmit({
    anoLetivo1,
    curso1,
    unidadeCurricular1,
    dataInicio1,
    dataFinal1,
  }) {
    carregarCursos().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaCurso(value.filter((curso) => curso.nome === curso1));
    });

    carregarDisciplinas().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaDisciplina(
        value.filter((disciplina) => disciplina.nome === unidadeCurricular1)
      );
    });

    carregarPlanoCurso().then((value) => {
      setPlan(value);
      setResPesquisaPlano(
        value.filter((plano) => plano.id_disci === resPesquisaDisciplina.id)
      );
    });

    carregarEdicoes().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaEdicao(
        value.filter(
          (edicao) => edicao.id_disciplina === setResPesquisaDisciplina.id
        )
      );
    });

    console.log(resPesquisaPlano);
  }
```

My problem is how to make the method carregarPlanoCurso() wait for the execution of the carregarCursos() method to finish executing for only then I can make sure that the searchCourse search variable is not undefined and make the call to api passing this variable as a parameter in the url:

Problem focus:

```
carregarCursos().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaCurso(value.filter((curso) => curso.nome === curso1));
    });

carregarPlanoCurso().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaPlano(
        value.filter((plano) => plano.id_disci === resPesquisaDisciplina.id)
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this way:

```js
carregarCursos().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaCurso(value.filter((curso) => curso.nome === curso1));
    }).then(() => carregarPlanoCurso().then((value) => {
      setResPesquisaPlano(
        value.filter((plano) => plano.id_disci === resPesquisaDisciplina.id)
      );
    }));
```

When you use a promise, JavaScript will not wait for that promise to resolve or reject. It will put this call in another part of the event loop and continue executing your code.

If I could, I want to suggest a change inside your handleSubmit function like this:

```js
function handleSubmit({
    anoLetivo1,
    curso1,
    unidadeCurricular1,
    dataInicio1,
    dataFinal1,
  }) {
    try {
      const {data: cursos} = await carregarCursos();
      setResPesquisaCurso(cursos.filter((curso) => curso.nome === curso1));

      const {data: disciplinas} = await carregarDisciplinas();
      setResPesquisaDisciplina(disciplinas.filter((disciplina) => disciplina.nome === unidadeCurricular1);
      // rest of your code using this approach.
    } catch (err) {
      // handle with your error
    }
  }
```

Doing this way JavaScript will wait for the promise resolves or reject.

Comment: it would not be redundant to do await carregarCursos() since the methods are already declared with async?